# Call Synapse pipeline with a notebook activity in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I tried to execute a Synapse pipeline with notebook in ADF by following the instructions on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-synapse-notebook):

[image]

The 1st Web Activity succeeded but the Until activity failed. It contains the expression:

```
@or(
    or(
        equals('Succeeded',activity('Get run status').output.status)
        ,equals('Failed',activity('Get run status').output.status)
        )
        ,equals('Cancelled',activity('Get run status').output.status)
    )
```

The error is:

*Unable to process expressions for action 'MainGet Pipeline Status': 'The expression 'or(or(equals('Succeeded',activity('Get run status').output.status),equals('Failed',activity('Get run status').output.status)),equals('Cancelled',activity('Get run status').output.status))' cannot be evaluated because property 'status' doesn't exist, available properties are 'code, message, target, details, error, ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, executionDuration, durationInQueue, billingReference'.*

It's very explicit but when I check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/pipeline-run/get-pipeline-run?tabs=HTTP) for the pipeline run parameters output, the *success* parameter should be present. Where does the error come from? Is it an access problem? I gave to ADF the access role "execute/run Synapse pipeline" as requested.

The Until activity contains a web activity and wait activity:

[image]

I noticed that my configuration for the "Get run status" doesn't have the same exact configuration as the Microsoft documentation:

[image]

Comment: Replace ```'Get run status'``` with ```'Call Synapse Pipeline with Notebook'``` in that expression

Comment: Hello Aswin, thanks for your reply. However, I still have the same error. In the documentation, it's explicitly written 'Get run status'

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue by giving Synapse Administrator role to my ADF instead of Synapse User and Synapse Credential User roles. I don't think it's the best approach.